# Creating an SVN repository from an eclipse java project

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating a project under eclipse that is to be shared by several developers.
The instructions I found for creating an svn repository said to:

1. svnadmin create /var/svn/draw
2. create a directory with my project on the server, make directories under it including trunk
3. put all code under trunk.

I copy in all the code, which is in src/ as usual for eclipse.

The problem is, when I check it out into eclipse, it's got directory trunk as well:

trunk/src/...

This means I have to change the project definitions.
First question: Can I create a project, and administer it in subversion directly from eclipse?

Second:  If not, how can I create the project in subversion so that its directory structure and eclipse project's are the same?  Do I just have to initially create a trunk directory? Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the overall folder structure here?  Are you just putting the code files in ./trunk/src/ and keeping other files related to the project outside of ./trunk/?  This may be a silly question, I'm just trying to get a feel for your SVN experience here.  The eclipse project shouldn't be aware of the ./trunk/ folder if everything in the project is relative to its own root path and ./trunk/ is that root path.

Comment: Thanks,

It's obvious now, I should have specified the URL with /trunk on it, and I think I had forgotten to copy some .files to the trunk directory, since they didn't show.

Comment: Is there any way to just say "create a new svn repository out of this project at this URL?

Comment: Inside of eclipse?  I don't know, I've actually never used it :)  In my experience with Visual Studio I've generally made it a point to keep VS and SVN blissfully unaware of each other, as I tend to see source control as a more filesystem-based thing.  Kind of a separation of concerns, I guess.  It's worked pretty well so far.  All the IDE knows is that it has a project open, it doesn't care if it's trunk or a branch or in source control at all.

Comment: Also, you're the first person to mark one of my responses as an answer.  Thanks for the positive reinforcement!

Comment: *Is there any way to just say "create a new svn repository out of this project at this URL?*

Yes: right-click on the project, team -> share